# show image in longitude, latitude position without annotation in titanium

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, titanium

I ned to chow some interest points in a map in titanium. I have don it withe the annotation but when i click on it the title box appears even when i don't define any title. So how can e put an image in some location without the title box when i click on the image?

this is my annotation:

```
var mountainView = Ti.Map.createAnnotation({
                latitude : latitude,
                longitude : longitude,
                image : Pino.toBlob(),
                animate : false,
                subtitle : "",
                title : "",
                myid : 1
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the InfoWindow, set the property `showInfoWindow` to `false` : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.Annotation-property-showInfoWindow